# Matplotlib boxplot with broken x-axis for outlier

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

I want to plot some text statistics in a boxplot, but I can't get it the way I want. I would like the mean to be a orange line in the box, and the median a blue one. Because the maximum number of tokens is so much larger than the other values, the whole boxplot becomes skewed. Ideally I would like to break the x-axis so that the other values become better visable. Also, this does not actually seem to plot the values I gave, but just calculates new statistics from the given values.

I have the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {
    "min_tokens": 84,
    "max_tokens": 11254,
    "mean_tokens": 339.48,
    "median_tokens": 266,
    "std_tokens": 234.83
}

values = list(data.values())

plt.boxplot(values, vert=False, widths=0.6)
plt.title("Boxplot of Token Statistics")
plt.xlabel("Token Count")
plt.ylabel("Dataset 1")
plt.show()
```

Image:
[image]

Comment: I think you want `bxp` rather than `boxplot` if you are passing the stats in https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bxp.html

Comment: Thank you !!! How have I been googling this for hours and not found this